# Forbid changing activity on cancell button

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application I use Intent to open new activity. But if I press physical cancel button on phone - the application returns to previous activity.

How to disable this?

Comment: Just write `finish()`. and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as physical "cancel" button. You probably mean "back" button.
The simplest way is to finish an Activity that should not be opened on back press.

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Also read
[Navigation with Back and Up](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)